# proper query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had some help with this code:

```
    SELECT *, IF(newcost - cost > 500, newcost - cost, 0) as raiseby FROM
(
SELECT bp.*, b.company,(IF(bp.cost*1.2 < ls.maximumbid, bp.cost*1.2, bp.cost)) as newcost
FROM `windows_brands_products` bp
LEFT JOIN `windows_brands` b
ON bp.brand_id = b.id
JOIN Windows_last_submissions ls
JOIN windows_materials dm
WHERE ls.username = '$current_user->user_login'
AND bp.width = ROUND(ls.width) 
AND bp.height = ROUND(ls.height) 
AND bp.material IN (dm.name) 
AND bp.type = ls.type 
AND IF (ls.minimumbid != '0.00',bp.cost BETWEEN ls.minimumbid AND ls.maximumbid,bp.cost <= ls.maximumbid)
ORDER BY b.company ASC
) as temptable
```

The goal is to display a line stating that the user missed a (or some) companies by $500 and state how much the user needs to increase their max. bid (ls.maximum) in order to come within parameters of the query.  It looks to me like it will look something like:

```
echo 'If you increase your maximum bid by '.$row->raiseby.',. $row->temptable.'can perform your installation';
```

I don't seem to get a positive response by using that statement...My assumptions could also be off about the way to reference each "row".
  Am I wrong to assume that when you use "AS" parameter in sql the word to the right becomes the new row name?
  Anyone have any idea as to how I could word this query to achieve my results?
Thanks

EDIT*  I'm having a problem with sqlfiddle showing an error I can't figure out.  it states 'incorrect integer value: column 'id' row 1':

```
CREATE TABLE windows_brands
(
id int(11),
company varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO windows_brands
VALUES ('1','Anderson');

CREATE TABLE windows_brands_products
(
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
brand_id int(11),
width decimal(12,2),
height decimal(12,2),
material varchar(30),
type varchar(30),
cost decimal(12,2),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO windows_brands_products
VALUES ('','2','30','36','wood','double hung','1500.00');

CREATE TABLE Windows_submissions
(
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30),
username varchar(12),
width decimal(12,2),
height decimal(12,2),
chosenmaterial varchar(30),
type varchar(30),
minimumbid decimal(12,2),
maximumbid decimal(12,2),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO Windows_submissions
VALUES ('','Casey','caseys','30','36','wood','double     hung','1000.00','1700.00');

CREATE TABLE windows_materials
(
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO windows_materials
VALUES ('','wood');
```

Can you see what the problem is - I've been looking it over for a while and can't see it.

This query works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22a74/1

In the query I'm trying to get to work...If, say, I make a maximumbid of $300 (for example) more than what the company charges, I should be able to echo something in a loop like, the nearest company is ____ and is $300 more than your maximumbid.  I just don't know how to reference the aliases like 'raiseby' and 'temptable'.  If I put that query into sqlfiddle 0 results show...which I want the same results like the company and the newcost to show- but also I want to let the user know how much they missed the target if, say, no results show.

Comment: `AS` creates an alias for the column, not the row. Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data, and show the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Here's a fiddle... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d5d3

Comment: If storing materials with an id then surely the submissions table would reference the id, as opposed to the material?!? Also, the submissions table should hold the username/user_id only, and no other information about the user.

Comment: Finally, the user's maximum bid is larger than the price of the product, so I don't see how this data set is representative of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for that Strawberry!